# Stepping through PL/SQL that runs from shell

Tags: sql, oracle, shell, plsql

The software I work on is a series of processes. Some of them are in java, some are pure shell and some are PL/SQL that is embedded in .sh scripts. I know there is a function for debugging and stepping through pl/sql for SQL Developer but as i understand that only works for PL/SQL that is compiled on the DB? Ours just runs straight from the shell script. Is there any way I can debug the PL/SQL line by line with breakpoints and such without compiling it to the DB?

Comment: Not within a shell script. IDEs such as PL/SQL Developer can debug anonymous blocks. Would that do?

Comment: Sorry thats what i mean. Some kind of progrma to run the PL/SQL script with against the DB to debug. From what I read the PL/SQL had to be on the DB to debug it with SQL Developer? Am I wrong? Just putting the script in SQL Developer doesn't allow me to debug it

Comment: Looks like [Oracle SQL Developer can do it](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/05/using-sql-developer-to-debug-your-anonymous-plsql-blocks/), as well as [PL/SQL Developer](https://www.allroundautomations.com/plsqldev.html). TOAD might but I try to avoid it. What do you have?

Comment: SQL Developer. I'll try the tutorial you linked.

Comment: Haven't tried it myself and it looks like you have to jump through some hoops, but it's free. In PL/SQL Developer you just put your code in a Test window and click the 'Start debugger' button, but it's commercial software so might not be available at your site.